# is the alphabetical word order subject to copyright?

Tags: copyright

I want to prepare a dictionary(English to Turkish) consisting of example sentences And for a list of English words, I use "Oxford Dictionary of Current English". Is the alphabetical word order subject to copyright? ( ı will not use definitions of words)

Comment: The short answer is "no". It is an idea not a specific expression of an idea.

Comment: The order is not, but the list of words may be.

Comment: I mean word order : abandon, abase, abashed, abate. is this subject to copyright? Can I use this word order for my dictionary?

Comment: The example sentences are probably considered to be creative expressions and therefore may be subject to copyright protection.

Comment: what about word order?

Comment: It appears that you are using 'word order' to include the actual words "abandon, anbashed, abate". This is not correct English; *word order* means only the placement if of those three words one after another (which is not subject to copyright). A dictionary without definitions is a *word list* which can indeed be copyrighted, so that merely copying Oxford is not legal; you would need to do your own word-finding.

Answer (score 2):

Alphabetical order is a "fact", not an "expression" so it is not subject to copyright. For the Latin alphabet, order was established millenia ago. It is unclear who established current Turkish alphabetical order for ç, ğ, ı, ö, ş, ü, but it was probably an official government decision, and under At. 31 of Turkish copyright law, "Duplication, dissemination, adaptation or otherwise use of the laws, rules, regulations, notifications, circular letters and juridical decisions which are officially promulgated or announced is free"